# adjustResize not working in full screen mode in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I used `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in theme so adjustResize didn't work out. Can anyone has solution for it.

Note: Code is in jetpack compose